# create a new series which base on other two series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am a newcomer in python.
There is a question about how to get a new series from the other two.
for example

```
a  b 
1  6 
4  7
5  8
8  9
```

then if a is odd then b * 2 and a is even * 3， after that we want to get a new series.

```
c
1 is odd ? 6 * 2 : 6 * 3
4 is odd ? 7 * 2 : 7 * 3
5 is odd ? 8 * 2 : 8 * 3
8 is odd ? 9 * 2 : 9 * 3
```

=======>

```
c
12
21
16
27
```

Answer (score 6):

Look ma, no operators:

```
df['a'].mod(2).rsub(3).mul(df['b'])

0    12
1    21
2    16
3    27
dtype: int64
```

---

You can also use `np.where` to get the multiplicands, instead of multiplying inside the expression. This way you only have to multiply once at the end (multiplication is expensive!):

```
df['b'] * np.where(df['a'] % 2, 2, 3)

0    12
1    21
2    16
3    27
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @Wen-Ben Look, looks like a _maths_ bug ;))

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you need `np.where` with `%`

> ```
> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the
> first argument by the second
> ```

```
np.where(df.a%2,df.b*2,df.b*3)
Out[1115]: array([12, 21, 16, 27], dtype=int64)
df['c']= np.where(df.a%2,df.b*2,df.b*3)
```

Ummm maybe using decimal covert the binary

```
(-df.a.map(bin).str[-1].astype(int)+3)*df.b
Out[1125]: 
0    12
1    21
2    16
3    27
dtype: int64
```